# react tailwind css not getting applied when served from node

Tags: reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css

I am serving my react build from a node server. Post build I am moving the build folder from the UI folder to a different location and serving from there.
But when doing so the tailwind css are not getting applied.
below are the configuration, Any help on this would be appreciated.

tailwind.config.ts

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "blue-100": "#0071DC",
        "grey-10": "#F1F1F2",
      },
      screens: {
        sm: 0,
        md: "37.5rem",
        lg: "56.25rem",
        xl: "75rem",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

webpack config

```
import ModuleFederationPlugin from "webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin.js"
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import dotenv from "dotenv"
import pkg from 'webpack';
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin"
import tailwindcss from "tailwindcss"
const {DefinePlugin} = pkg;
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);

const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

export default {
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './src/main.tsx',
    output: {
        publicPath: process.env.MODULE_PATH,
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'module-build'),
        filename: 'bundled.js',
        crossOriginLoading: 'anonymous'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js/,
                resolve: {
                    fullySpecified: false
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options:{
                    compilerOptions:{
                        "noEmit": false,
                        "allowImportingTsExtensions": false,
                    }
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        '@babel/preset-env',
                        '@babel/preset-react'
                    ],
                    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: [
                    {
                loader: 'file-loader', // Use 'file-loader' or 'url-loader' here
                options: {
                        name: 'images/[name].[ext]', // You can configure the output path and file name as needed
                },
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'] // ?name=[name].[ext] is only necessary to preserve the original file name
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
        alias: {
            "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        new ModuleFederationPlugin(
            {
                name: 'remote_app',
                filename: 'remote.js',
                library: { type: 'var', name: 'remote_app' },
                exposes: {
                    './RemoteApp': path.resolve(__dirname,'./src/module.tsx'),
                },
                shared: {
                    react: { },
                    'react-dom': {},
                    '@reduxjs/toolkit': {},
                    'react-router-dom': {},
                    'react-redux': {},
                    
                    "tailwindcss":{}
                }
            }
        ),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
        }),
        new DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': JSON.stringify(dotenv.config().parsed)
        })
    ]
};
```